# Create a dynamic page for all US cities in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have a WordPres based site, where I have some business listings. The listings are custom post types.
I can browse a listing from front end like follows: http://www.example.com/listings/business-name.

Also the post type has tags associated with named in `Functions.php` as Locations and I can put city name as tags and browse listing as http://www.example.com/locations/city-name.

Unfortunately tags won't support Hierarchy and hence I can't make something like this:

```
domain/locations/california/losangeles
```

What I need:

I want the URL to be something like:

```
domain/california/losangeles
```

and this must show all listings in that city. **I don't want that `listings` or `locaions` word in URL** also I want to maintain a hierachy structure  i.e.

```
california/losangeles/
```

How can I reach that goal?

Comment: Hey, did you know there's a site like stackoverflow that's just for Wordpress? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/  It might be worth searching and/or asking there, too.

Comment: Yeah, been there a lot of times.

Comment: When you've asked or searched there, what kind of results have you gotten?

Comment: They don't answer my question.